# Remove border between dropdown and drop down menu on Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I set the CSS setting to display the bootstrap `.dropdown` and `.dropdown-menu` looks like merged (without border) like second menu at following image?

[image]

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
}

.navbar-default {}

.dropdown {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background: white;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  max-height: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 400px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
     
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bottom border of the `a` element with some z-index and negative margin to get it to overlay the border on the menu. The default selector is pretty heavy, but it works.

You'll also need to move left-hand menu dropdowns to the left to hide the gap, and right hand dropdowns to the right. You can accomplish this with `translateX(-1px)` and `translateX(1px)` respectively. I recommend the transform because there seems to be an animation delay if you use margins.

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
}

.navbar-default {}

.dropdown {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background: white;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  max-height: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 400px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* NEW CSS */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:hover>a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    z-index: 10;
} 

.dropdown-menu {
  transform: translateX(-1px);
}

.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
  transform: translateX(1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
     
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Xhynk, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Nice fix, I had the same idea, but with a pseudo-element + border.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  max-height: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top: none;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

(notice the two additional properties at the end)

Comment: Thanks pdaniels0013, this is good but by removing the top border some part of the droepdown menu is with out style

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? maybe post a screenshot of what the issue is?

Comment: [**This**](https://i.imgur.com/0B2GLh9.png) is what you'll get, the whole border is removed, but more than just the width of the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the color transparent, that way you don't need to worry about changing the spacing

```
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My method consists of adding a pseudo-element for .dropdown with `border: 1px solid white;` and placing it on top of .dropdown with `z-index: 2;`

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
}

.navbar-default {}

.dropdown {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown:hover::after {
  content: '';                    /* added */
  width: 100%;                    /* added */
  position: absolute;             /* added */
  border-bottom: 1px solid white; /* added */
  z-index: 2;                     /* added */
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background: white;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  max-height: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 400px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```